# What is the equalent for navigationOptions in React Navigation V6.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

In V4.0 we could configure any screen inside it using navigationOptions.
for example.

In HomeScreen component we could configure it using

```
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = { ...config }
```

what is the equalent in V6.0?

Answer (score 0):

in  v6  if  you  want  to add  navigation option you  can  use the  simple option like  this

```
HomeScreen:{
    screen:HomeScreen,
    navigationOption:{...config}
}
```

Comment: I am aware that you can add options prop to Stack.screen component but I want to able to do it in the HomeScreen component itself. or can you point me to the relavant docs?